# Is there a way to catch 500 errors in django python?

Tags: python, django, http, django-middleware

I would like to catch 500 exception and return a http 4XX exception instead. Using "except Exception" will catch all exceptions which is not desired. I was wondering is there a way to catch only 500 errors

```
try:
   <code>
except <Exception class>:
   return http 404 reponse
```

I searched a lot but couldn't figure out how to do the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need [middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception)

Comment: There is no 500 exception. The WSGI handler catches _any_ exception and returns a 500 response if there is one, save a few special cases such as `Http404` or `PermissionDenied`.

Comment: So should i use except Exception: ? Thats the only way ? @knbk

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what it is you want exactly, so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that returning 404 instead of 500 is a good idea, but you can acheive this by defining a [custom error handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) for 500 errors.

In your urls.py:

```
handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'
```

In your views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_custom_error_view(request):
    """
    Return a 404 response instead of 500.
    """
    return HttpResponse("error message", status_code=404)
```